# How to Dynamically add attributes from csv file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I am new to RoR. 
I want to dynamically add attributes from a csv file so that my code would be able to dynamically read any csv file and build the db (i.e. convert any CSV file into Ruby objects)

I was using the below code

```
csv_data = File.read('myData.csv')
csv = CSV.parse(csv_data, :headers => true, :header_converters => :symbol)

csv.each do |row|
  MyModel.create!(row.to_hash)
end
```

However it will fail for the following example

**myData.csv**

```
Name,id
foo,1
bar,10
```

**myData2.csv**

```
Name,value
foo,1
bar,10
```

It will result an error for myData2 because the value is not a parameter in MyModel

> unknown attribute 'value' for MyModel.

I have thought about using send(:attrAccessor, name) but I was not sure how can I integrate it when reading from csv, any ideas ?

Comment: What attributes does your model have in the database?

Comment: So what _exactly_ is the problem here? If you're saying `MyModel.create({value: 10})` and the model doesn't have `value` field, what did you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it properly but you can also bulk upload the records

```
csv_data = 
  CSV.read("#{Rails.root}/myData.csv", 
           headers: true,
           header_converters: :symbol
  ).map(&:to_hash)

MyModel.create(csv_data)
```

NOTE: If the data is going to be same you can use **`seeds.rb`**

Comment: The bulk idea is really good. But it still updates attributes/params predefined by MyModel. The problem is that the csv header changes from one file to another. I updated the question for an example

Comment: You have to pass proper headers in order to avoid the errors and inserting values in incorrect column

Comment: You can rename the headers that's not a hectic task

Comment: Can't I dynamically add params to MyModel from the csv headers ? 
Does it have to be hardcoded ?

Comment: You are talking about attributes. You will need to first add the columns to that model and to do that you need to write a migration

Comment: You can add columns using some code but migrations will not be there which will cause problem next time you need to reset your db